# Decrypt aes-file in iOS encrypted using a tool from AESCrypt.com

Tags: android, iphone, aes, encryption

I'm working on an app that among other things plays sound files. My problem is the sound files are encrypted with a command line tool that can be found on [aescrypt.com](https://www.aescrypt.com/download/) just providing the file and a password. I have used the java-code on aescrypt.com to successfully decrypt the files in the android app but I can't for the life of me not get it to work in iOS.

I have tried to decrypt all the bytes of the file and the bytes that does not include the header of the file. I get a result set of bytes back but it won't play and the estimated length of the sound is about one fourth of the actual length.

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, self.length);
unsigned char* encrypteddata = malloc(range.length);
[self getBytes:encrypteddata range:range];
size_t outSize;
unsigned char* result = malloc(range.length + 16);
CCCryptorStatus status = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0x00, decryptkey, sizeof(decryptkey), nil, encrypteddata, self.length, result, self.length + 16, &outSize);
NSData *returnData = nil;
if (status == kCCSuccess) {
    returnData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:result length:outSize];
}
```

The decryptkey is just the bytes from the password used to encrypt the file.

I have been working on a solution for at least a week now and not made any progress. There are so many things that can be done wrong and so many possible (and impossible) combinations.

**Update:**
What I need is a tool that is simple enough for our customer to use to encrypt the sound files on their end and also is simple for the apps both on Android and iOS to decrypt on the other end. It does not need to be very secure, it only needs to prevent the common user on Android from just opening and play the file from disc. If aescrypt.com tools isn't optimal for this, I  gladly welcome other suggestions.

Comment: Hi Sanna, have you managed to find any solutions for iOS platform? I am having the same issue, I have files that were encrypted using aescrypt.com programs and I need to decrypt them on iOS. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Uygar Y We ended up using another solution in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AESCrypt format carries significant configuration information. Most of the format is detailed at their site ([aes_file_format.html](http://www.aescrypt.com/aes_file_format.html)). This page doesn't explain their custom KDF, unfortunately. You'll have to use or reverse-engineer their `encrypt_stream` function in `aescrypt.c`:

```
// Hash the IV and password 8192 times
memset(digest, 0, 32);
memcpy(digest, IV, 16);
for(i=0; i<8192; i++)
{
    sha256_starts(  &sha_ctx);
    sha256_update(  &sha_ctx, digest, 32);
    sha256_update(  &sha_ctx,
                    (unsigned char*)passwd,
                    (unsigned long)passlen);
    sha256_finish(  &sha_ctx,
                    digest);
}
```

They don't use CommonCryptor, so if you want hardware-optimized code, you'll have to reimplement this format yourself in CommonCryptor.

Note that your decrypt code has no IV, no KDF, and no HMAC, so anything that actually encrypted that way would be highly insecure. AESCrypt does provide a proper IV and HMAC, and its KDF is likely secure, though non-standard, so it is a reasonable choice.

Comment: The files does not need to be totally secure. The goal is just that the common user should not be able to play the sound files directly from disc in Android where it is possible to browse the application files on the phone. Now I believe I have chosen the wrong method to encrypt the files. This shifting bytes stuff is not my thing.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you stick to that AESCrypt applications? They write their custom header to the encrypted file.
They distribute source code, which will give you enough information about how to decrypt this (and, probably you'll be able to re-use their sources). Check their AESCryptWorkerThreads.cpp in AES crypto source code.

Comment: I wanted to find at tool that would be fairly easy to use by our customer who will provide the encrypted sound files in the future. I had no idea that aescrypt.com used their own file-format. Thanks for the input.